# Why is Every Request Matching my nginx Redirect?

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm having some problems with my nginx settings.

I have one server that should be serving two domains. One domain should just be performing a redirect. One domain should be performing a redirect for www urls, and then serving up my uwsgi application.

For some reason, everything matches the first thing it finds. Which is odd.

Here's the .conf file

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name russellrollins.com;
    return 301 $scheme://blog.russellrollins.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.russellrollins.com;
    return 301 $scheme://blog.russellrollins.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.playbeercan.com;
    return 301 $scheme://playbeercan.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name playbeercan;
  charset utf-8;
  client_max_body_size 75M;

  location / { try_files $uri @playbeercan; }
  location @playbeercan {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/playbeercan/playbeercan_uwsgi.sock;
  }
}
```

Instead of sending:

russellrollins.com -> blog.russellrollins.com

www.russellrollins.com -> blog.russellrollins.com

www.playbeercan.com -> playbeercan.com

playbeercan.com -> uwsgi app

It sends everything I try to blog.russellrollins.com. Everything seems to match the first server name.

I even tried removing all the redirects except the first one, and it's still matching everything.

The only setting in the nginx.conf file I've changed is the server_names_hash_bucket_size. Which seems unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `server_name` `directive` to handle both `blog.russellrollins.com` and `playbeercan.com`, otherwise it would take the first `server_name` as default, or you could use `default_server` to set the default.

Comment: So the correct solution was to add the default_server directive. However, one thing I would advise is to use 302 redirects until you've got everything right. Since my incorrect redirects were getting cached and screwing up my troubleshooting.